# Qt C++ android multi-screen applications

Tags: android, c++, qt, screen-size

I have a problem with scaling Qt apps (games) for android devices.

On the internet it has been said to make your app to adjust to any screen size you have to use QML and integrate it in your Qt application code.

Is it correct or is it some better way to solve my problem? I need advice what should I do first?

As far as i understand i have to learn QML.

Comment: There is no specific need for QML - QLayouts take care of scaling contents based on size of app and your sizepolicies. Scaling based on resolution (like support of highdpi) is completely another stoly but is also not related to QML.

Comment: whta if i do not use any layouts, just a window 400x400 with caracters?
Do i have to resize it to my screen resolution and all?

Comment: you would have to set size for window and position widget where you want. But better use layouts - read this guide with examples to learn more about qt's layout system - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-layouts.html